# Can any one tell me what this tool is?

Tags: tools

[image][image][image]What is this?

What is this tool used for?
it seems to be a stainless tool steel and has a round shaft with a triangle tip.

Comment: Some type of punch.  Another picture of the tip/end might help.  Right now it looks kind of flat.

Comment: the tip is flat, possibly looks like something has snapped off it.

Comment: New pictures help.  Looks like a grounded edge(abused), so maybe a chisel/punch.

Comment: The flats on the triangle look to be surface ground, which is a lot of effort for a punch/ chisel, and the ground tip is very shallow so it wouldn't have had much of a point before the abuse.

Comment: An [end mill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_mill) someone abused as a punch. Google *brenco* and you get "Lathes + Machine Tool Archive"

Comment: someone has been using it as a punch (because the other end is mushrooming)  but I don't think that was the original purpose.

Comment: it has a very long shank on it for an end mill (100mm). The end isnt mushrooming, it just looks that way because i was doing a spark test and ground it abit. its non magnetic and very hard

Answer (score 0):

It's a VERY limited use security bit, for screws generally used to secure wall panels in private spaces prone to vandalism. (I've mostly seen them in boy's bathrooms in schools). It's often called a tri-star bit.

Comment: it seems kind of flat faced,  tri star is not particularly obscure.

Comment: This was my initial thought, but... it's got a round shank, not hex, so it won't fit an impact driver (where 99% of bits are meant to go these days). There aren't any scratch marks on the shank from having been tightened down into a normal 3-jaw chuck (if it's much older). It's quite rather long to be a driver bit. OP believes it to be stainless steel which is rather uncommon for use as tool steel - it's too brittle.